# How to make a 'Responding Telegram Bot' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, telegram

I want to get people's text and respond to them.

Here's my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests; use App\config\Telegram;

class TelegramController extends Controller {

  public function Telegram(){
    $token = "token";
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token ;
    $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $content = json_decode($content, TRUE);

    $message = isset($content["message"]["text"]) ? $content["message"]["text"] : null;

    if($message == "/start"){
      $sendpm = "https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=Text";
      file_get_contents($sendpm);
    } else {
      $sendpm = "https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=Null";
      file_get_contents($sendpm);
    }
  }
}
```

However, - it seems to give a null-response, and I want to get it to respond with the user's text-message.

Comment: Can you add the route that your calling as well? And I assume that "token" is replaced by the real token from the Telegram-site? And that `$content`-variable looks a bit strange. If you can't show the real URL or path fram that `file_get_contents`, - can you then write a dummy-line, to see the format that line has? And or, - can you supply a link to the page/guide that you've followed on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good idea to use raw php. 
To avoid a lot of mistakes it is better to use the following libraries: https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core with [examples](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/example-bot/tree/master/Commands) or https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs

I prefer to use [This](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core) with laravel ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385842/commands-not-recognised-in-php-telegram-bot-on-a-laravel-project/48609386#answer-48609386))